# how to extract multiple attributes from a ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a student array object which returns multiple attributes. I need to extract only specific attributes from this array. Here is the code that I have tried

```
@project.each do |p|
          @students << Student.find_by_id(:id => p.receiver_id, :select => "first_name, last_name")
        end
```

But it is showing Unknown keys :id.
I need only the first name and the last name to be inserted in @students array. I am using rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because it should be:

```
@project.each do |p|
  @students << Student.find_by_id(p.receiver_id)
end
```

If you only want the first names and last names, then you might consider:

```
@project.each do |p|
  student = Student.find_by_id(p.receiver_id)
  @students << { :first_name => student.first_name, :last_name => student.last_name }
end
```

If you want an array, then:

```
@project.each do |p|
  student = Student.find_by_id(p.receiver_id)
  @students << [student.first_name, student.last_name ]
end
```

The first version would give you an array of hashes. The second version would give you an array of arrays.